# Get the latest caret position among multiple contenteditable div and append image to the div where the cursor was present lastly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable, caret

I need to append an image among multiple content-editable div based on the fact which was edited most recently. Also, contenteditable div in itself contains HTML(not just text) so there might be multiple nodes present inside those divs. To understand the problem more correctly here is a [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258104/)

```js
$('#img-div').on('click',function(){
  //logic for appending according to latest caret position

  //if caret wasnt in any content editable div then do this
  $('#div-4').append($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="img-div">
      <img src="https://creww.io/assets/images/creww-coin.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-1">
          Div 1 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-2">
          Div 2 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-3">
          Div 3 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-4">
          Div 4 here
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258105/

Answer (score 0):

You can get present lastly `mouseover` event.

```js
$('#img-div').on('click',function(){
 

  //if caret wasnt in any content editable div then do this
  lastDiv.append($(this).html());
  //$('#divApp').append(lastDiv.html());
 
});

 //logic for appending according to latest caret position
var lastDiv;
$('div[id*="div-"]').mouseover(function() {
lastDiv =$( this );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="img-div">
      <img src="https://creww.io/assets/images/creww-coin.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-1">
          Div 1 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-2">
          Div 2 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-3">
          Div 3 here
       </div>
       <div contenteditable="true" id="div-4">
          Div 4 here
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divApp"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not exactly what I want to achieve. However by using your function I can find which was the last div where mouseover was there but I also want to append the div not from the last position but wherever the cursor was present last time inside this div

Comment: @AchalGupta i have update code so append the cursor was present last time inside this div. you can find in my code.

Comment: I would love to but my problem isnt solved completely. I wanna insert the image right wherever the cursor was last time the same way we insert image in a mail by drag drop(inserted next to our blinking cursor) I wanna achieve the same using a click on image

Comment: @AchalGupta can you explain what is done and what need to done?

Comment: Lets break it into two problems : 1) I want to insert image in a contenteditable div right where my cursor was positioned last. Similar to the way the image get inserted while composing mail from gmail. Image gets inserted wherever our cursor was present.(The contenteditable div contains tags inside it not simply text)

Comment: Secondly there are multiple such divs I need to find which div was latest in focus.
Using your code I can successfully solve second problem but first problem is still unsolved.